# Remove SID from category filter URLs

Tags: magento-1.7, url, seo

When the user filters the products according to the size, say 34,5
the filter button creates a URL like this:

(URL 1) http://www.turquoise.me/tango-women-shoes#%21___SID=U&size=29

Which is actually 34,5 sized shoes filtered and displayed.

But while if you manually write

(URL 2) https://www.turquoise.me/tango-women-shoes/filter/size/34-5

You can get the same page as the shoes filtered as 34,5

Both do filter the products correctly, but the actual filter button when used, goes to URL 1 and I want the filter to go to URL 2. And I don't even want URL 1 to be created.

Comment: Hey there Baris. Welcome to Magento.SE! We're looking for questions with clear, concise answers. Please review the [help center](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for more information. Feel free to edit the question to be a bit less broad, more in the line of "how do I remove SID from the URL?"

Comment: Hi, those are similar questions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/38502/how-to-remove-sid-from-url and http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68109/get-category-url-from-id-without-sid. Maybe you'll find your answer already there.

Comment: Hello Anna, thank you for the answer, I read that solution but I want the customers to be logged in, when I remove the SID , it says it doesn't allow customers to be logged in.